# how to get different fields from different records from same table based on some condition in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1OfG.png)

```
Date    Unit-1      Unit-2
1/1/2017    250        300
1/2/2017    150        225
1/3/2017    320       null
1/4/2017    null       200
1/5/2017    100        200
```

Please help me to how to get result in mysql

Comment: can you mock up an example of what you are trying to select and explain what the conditions are?

Comment: we need more information.    Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following query:

```
SELECT 
`date`,
TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM (GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN unit='Unit-1' THEN amount ELSE '' END),',','') AS `Unit-1`,
TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM (GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN unit='Unit-2' THEN amount ELSE '' END),',','') AS `Unit-2`
FROM myTable GROUP BY `date`;
```

Is this what you want from the records shown in the image?